# cursor for loop & dynamic SQL - Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to write a procedure that takes in a list of tables and date_column to create some row_counts by calendar dates for reconciliation purposes.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  VALUES ('tbl1', 'created_date')
       , ('tbl2', 'modify_date')
       , ('tbl3', 'last_seen_date')
  ) t(tbl, dt)

+----+--------------+
|TBL |DT            |
+----+--------------+
|tbl1|created_date  |
|tbl2|modify_date   |
|tbl3|last_seen_date|
+----+--------------+
```

---

I'm connected to Snowflake via a JDBC connection using Datagrip - so I assume I need to follow the classic SnowSQL part of the documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html#cursor-based-for-loops

[image]

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$

  DECLARE
    dt text
    , tbl text;
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dt, tbl from t;
    BEGIN
      FOR record in c1 DO
        dt := record.dt
        tbl := record.tbl
        stmt =: 'SELECT COUNT(*)' ||
           CONCAT(', DAYOFMONTH(', $dt, ')') ||
           CONCAT('\n FROM ', $tbl) ||
           CONCAT('\n WHERE YEAR(', $dt, ')', ' = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)') ||
           CONCAT('\n AND MONTH(', $dt, ')', ' = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)') ||
           '\n GROUP BY' ||
           CONCAT('\n DAYOFMONTH(', $dt, ')')
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt -- will adapt this to be an update statement eventually. 
      END FOR
      end;
$$
```

This returns a SQL Compilation error, I've tried a few different variations of this but I'm none the wiser on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the query string which makes it almost unreadable it could be rewritten using bind variables:

```
DECLARE
    dt text;
    tbl text;
    stmt text;
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dt, tbl from t;
BEGIN
  FOR record in c1 DO
    dt := record.dt;
    tbl := record.tbl;
    
    stmt := 'INSERT INTO result(cnt, day_of_month)
             SELECT COUNT(*), DAYOFMONTH(IDENTIFIER(?)) AS day_of_month
             FROM TABLE(?)
             WHERE YEAR(IDENTIFIER(?)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
               AND MONTH(IDENTIFIER(?)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
             GROUP BY day_of_month';
             
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt USING (dt, tbl, dt, dt); 
     
     RETURN stmt;
  END FOR;
END;
```

If column or table is parameter it should be wrapped with `IDENTIFIER`/`TABLE` funtion.

---

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t AS
SELECT  'col1' AS dt, 'tab1' AS tbl UNION ALL 
SELECT  'col2' AS dt, 'tab1' ;

CREATE TABLE tab1(col1 DATE, col2 DATE) AS
SELECT CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE()-40;

CREATE TABLE result(cnt INT, day_of_month INT);

SELECT * FROM result;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'm marking this as the correct answer as it avoids using hacky string concatenation (which it self was based on my question)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of minor issues like missing semicolons etc. Here is the fixed script:

```
DECLARE
    dt text;
    tbl text;
    stmt text;
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT dt, tbl from t;
BEGIN
  FOR record in c1 DO
    dt := record.dt;
    tbl := record.tbl;
    stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*)' ||
       CONCAT(', DAYOFMONTH(', dt, ')') ||
       CONCAT('\n FROM ', tbl) ||
       CONCAT('\n WHERE YEAR(', dt, ')', ' = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)') ||
       CONCAT('\n AND MONTH(', dt, ')', ' = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)') ||
       '\n GROUP BY' ||
       CONCAT('\n DAYOFMONTH(', dt, ')');
   -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt; 
     RETURN stmt;
  END FOR;
END;
```

Comment: damn, what a noobish error! worked as execpted thanks Mr Atil!